# Safely sanitise user uploaded json in rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, erb

I have a page on my site which expects some user defined JSON to be parsed in Javascript.

I am trying to think of the best way to sanitise the JSON so that it can't have any XSS in it.

The simplest solution to allow users to upload JSON is this:

```
var someJSON = <%= @my_object.json_blob.html_safe %>;
```

However, this isn't secure since the the `json_blob` was uploaded by the user so it could have Javascript code and not be valid JSON.

The next option I thought of was this:

```
var someJSON = <%= JSON.parse(@my_object.json_blob).to_json.html_safe %>;
```

I think this is completely safe since it now has to be valid JSON and not Javascript code. Am I right in this?

The problem with that approach is that it is very unintuitive and involves converting it to a hash and then back to JSON again instead of just checking the validity of the JSON.

Finally, I could also check that the JSON is valid before uploading and only upload to the database if it is valid JSON. That way I wouldn't have to do any validation in the ERB file.

Which option seems like the best and most secure? Am I missing a more simple solution here?

Answer (score 1):

I think the best option is checking JSON structure on upload. It gives user a chance to fix his JSON. And you are not storing invalid data.

Also, you could use gems like **[json-schema](https://github.com/ruby-json-schema/json-schema)** to check not only validity, but JSON structure too.

Comment: Yeah I guess that would be the best. However, the user doesn't directly enter the JSON. it's through quill.js where the only way for it to be invalid is if it's malicious. But you are probably right even excluding that part

Comment: I think `JSON.parse` would be enough in this case. Anyway, you could use `json-schema` in the future: for validating complex input structure, for testing JSON API output, etc.